# Maven Web project with Maven java application as a dependency?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I have a simple java application - maven project in my Netbeans IDE.

After I created Maven Web Application and added first project as a dependency Netbeans shows that everything is OK, and I can use all methods as well.

But in runtime I am getting

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.dal.factory.PersistenceDaoFactory`

Is it possible to make web project depending on simple java application without creating multimodule java EE application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you need to install your first project locally:

```
mvn install:install-file       \
    -Dfile=<path-to-file>      \
    -DgroupId=<group-id>       \
    -DartifactId=<artifact-id> \
    -Dversion=<version>        \
    -Dpackaging=jar
```

Setting up NetBeans to use a project as a dependency isn't the same thing as having a Maven artifact you can use in other Maven projects; for Maven, you need to have it in a Maven repo.

Comment: Thank you, I right-clicked to the dependency in the dependency list of my web project and set the artifact manually(Pointed to compiled first-project.jar), now it works!